# While row with image and text

Tags: php, mysql, string

I know how to do the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($STRING)){
   // etc...
}
```

But I only know that how to do it with an image as large as the text itself.
I want something like this:

[image]

Of course the above with `while($row...`

Do I get that with float and margin or is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put a `float: left;` in the css for your image.